# Set Controller params in Rspec Testing

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

[image]

I want to write Capybara test for form but get an error on UI after submitting a form.

> Field Position doesn't have a default value

But this field non-present on the new.html view, it present in the Controller and Edit.html. How should I pass "position" params to the controller in my TEST.

Controller:

```
@issue_position = params[:issue_position].presence.try(:to_i)
```

_edit.html.erb:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'issue_position', @issue_position if @issue_position %>
```

Test:

```
within("#issue-form") do
  fill_in 'issue[subject]', with: 'Test_issue'
  fill_in 'issue[description]', with: 'Test_description'
end
click_button 'Create'
```

Comment: Please take care not to overwrite other people's edits here, [see the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57625119/revisions). You will see a system message if an edit is made while you have the editing window open.

Comment: When a real user is using your application how would that field be set? Does it actually work if you try and create your issue manually? It seems to me that Capybara is showing an actual bug in your application.  If your application does actually work manually then you'll need to edit your question to have the full test, full create action, and possibly the full new.html.erb assuming that's the template being used to render the page you're visiting

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in your test ,when you visit your page, you forgot to pass your `issue_position` params. Please add the code below:

`visit your_page_path({issue_position: 1})`

But as Thomas mention in comment the show up a weird behaviour of your app. Maybe you should display the input in you form when `issue_params` is empty in order to prévention this unfriendly behaviour for your user.

Answer (score 0):

I just add the migration with "default value" to my Database table column and run migrations and Everything start working!

Thanks to everyone!

```
class AddDefaultValueToIssue < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :issues, :position, :integer, default: 1
  end

  def down
    change_column :issues, :position, :integer, default: nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm It's like you are changing your `schema` because of your t'est. Sounds a bad practice Do you really need to have à default value in Your column?